# How to create a Makefile for an existing project

Tags: c++, makefile, autoconf

I'd like to create a Makefile for a moderately sized C++ project (~110 .cpp and .h files) that was created in Xcode.  I don't own a mac, so I can't just go into xcode and export a Makefile.

From my understanding of using Makefiles for simpler projects, I could go through and create a target in my Makefile for each .cpp file, including its prerequisites... but that would require manually looking through each file and sorting out what its dependencies are.

It's my understanding that autoconf is a good tool for this sort of problem, but I haven't been able to figure out how to set it up and I'm not even sure that it's the right tool for the job.  So before I go even further down this rabbit hole --

**What is the best way to create a Makefile for an existing project without one?**

Comment: Pretty much the bible of these tools is "Managing Projects with GNU Make, Third Edition By Robert Mecklenburg" which, luckily, is now available for free from http://oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/index.csp . Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to be a useful resource for learning make, but doesn't seem to have much about autoconf upon first glance.  Is there a similar book for autoconf?

Comment: Yes, there's "The Goat Book" available at http://sourceware.org/autobook/

Answer (score 0):

It is rather subjective as to the best tool. Perhaps look at [SCONS](http://www.scons.org/) or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) to compare for your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Pbxbuild](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Pbxbuild)  may help you.

> Pbxbuild (not to be confused with the OS X tool of the same name) is used to take Xcode project files and build the code. It does this by creating GNUmakefiles, and using Make to build those.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need -- is it a standard part of gnusteps that I can get with apt-get?  The github doesn't have any instructions on how its supposed to be used and/or installed.

Answer (score 0):

Any build system (generator) will require some learning on your part. I would suggest using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), if you do not mind that CMake will be required wherever anybody tries to build your source. Otherwise I would suggest using the Autoconf/Automake/Libtool combo.